# Got ckeditor-duplicated-modules when integrate ckeditor5 into Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor5

I tried to integrate ckeditor5 into my angular project but got `ckeditor-duplicated-modules`. I tried many ways

1. Add ckeditor classic build only, it works fine
2. Add ckeditor classic build and `Base64ImageUpload` plugin, it does not work
3. Extend my `ClassicEditor` from `ClassicEditorBase` but it does not work

Any one got the same issue ? and any solution for this one ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom build if you want to add modules.

You can read about Custom Builds [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html). Steps:

1. Fork one of the official builds.
2. Add modules which you need
3. Build it into JS file.
4. Add this file to your Angular project.
5. (optional) You can publish your build to NPM and use it.

You can check out my build as example. I use it in my Angular project. Here is the links [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-build-dailycoding) and [GitHub](https://github.com/MrBandaruk/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block)

Comment: thank you so much, I will try and get back to you soon

Comment: After reading through all the documentation, it's true. It seems you cannot add plugins if you npm install a default editor.