# ckeditor-duplicated-modules when installing SimpleUploadAdapter

Tags: webpack, build, ckeditor

I am following instructions to install the SimpleUploadAdapter

In my working directory after cloning : https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic.git

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload
```

I edit ckeditor.js and add these lines

```
import SimpleUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter';

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [...,,SimpleUploadAdapter]
```

Then I try to access the `sample/index.html` provided in the distribution and I got `ckeditor-duplicated-modules`

2 days stuck on this problem which should be common use cases for CKEditor !!

Perharps, it is elated to : 
[Got ckeditor-duplicated-modules when integrate ckeditor5 into Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829158/got-ckeditor-duplicated-modules-when-integrate-ckeditor5-into-angular-project)

Comment: you found any answers? i also have this problem with installing plugins in ckeditor 5.